# Is there a plugin for autocomplete with querying the URL when typing(keypress/keyup) in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to implement an autocomplete in jquery and I have checked with Jquery ui autocomplete but couldnt figure out.

I need to fetch data from a url as json or text, but i should do this every time the text is changed in the auto complete. I should not pull all the data and keep in the client side..

Please let me know if we have any straight forward implementation of this as a plugin or something.. I am new to jquery

Comment: [Detect when user type done](http://sdtuts.local/detect-when-user-type-done/)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with jquery ui autocomplete by giving a callback to `source`

```
$('#your_input').autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
    ...
      success: function( data ) {
        response( $.map( data.field, function( item ) {
          return {
    ...
```

See the [JSON example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp)

Matching results come from the server on each keypress

Comment: what is the story behind response() function where can i find the documentation for that.. i couldnt get that part...

Comment: @RajKumaran If you go on my link [JSON example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) you can view source to see the full code and in the [overview](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) you have the explanation on the `response()` callback

Comment: Here is simple method typeDone 
[Detect when user type done](http://sdtuts.local/detect-when-user-type-done)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

      $("#input_id").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'URL',
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                            filter: request.term // word being typed, can add additional params as needed
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(eval(data), function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.em_name,
                                    custom_val: item.custom_val,
                                    custom_val2: item.custom_val2
                                }
                            }));
                        }
                    })
                },
                maxLength: 2,   //length before search text gets submitted
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#custom_val_textbox").attr('value', ui.item.custom_val);
                    $("#custom_val_textbox2").attr('value', ui.item.custom_val2);
                }
            });

</script>
```